# How to display ForeignKey Data in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have relation of `Project` between `Tags` and a Project can have multiple tags, But I am unable to display the tags data in my template, I am trying to display data according to tag slug. But I ma getting error, Please let me know how I can display Tags data in my Template.

Here is my `urls.py` file...

```
    path('tag/<tag_slug>', views.projecttag, name='projecttag'),
```

here is my `models.py file...

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True, related_name='ProjectTags', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    tag_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def projecttag(request, tag_slug):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tags, tag_slug=tag_slug)
    project = Project.objects.filter(ProjectTags=tag)
    context = {'tag':tag, 'project':project}
    template_name = 'pages/tags.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my `tags.html` file...

```
{% for property in project %}
    <div class="single-property-box">
        {{property.name}}
    </div>
{% endfor %
```

Comment: Please add the error message.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understandings, you want to display tags that are connected with your '`project`' class. As you explain that a project can have multiple tags, so the '*ProjectTags*' field from your '`Project`' class must be multi-valued. But when you are filtering Projects in `projecttag` view, you are just checking `ProjectTags=tag`. Here `tag` is a single object. So instead you should check for `ProjectTags__in=tag`.

And if you already declared `Tags` class as *`ManyToManyRelation`* in Project class then there is no need to create *Foreign Key* constraint in tags class. As you didn't upload Project Class, so I don't have any idea about how you are relating *tags* class with it.